# Vary date time and drop post midnight values

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a number of datetime entries per patient_id and I want to keep the first datetime unchanged and the date the same for all the rest but vary their time component.  This is done by using another variable called frequency. The calculation is (24/frequency) and gives an output in interval hours to be added to the timestamp of that row.

What output I get from my code

```
timestamp             patient_id    frequency
2011-06-22 11:21:04   P10           2       
2011-06-22 11:21:12   P10           3       
2011-06-22 11:21:18   P10           4       
2011-06-22 11:21:24   P10           4
```

What I would like as an output from my existing code

```
timestamp             patient_id    frequency
2011-06-22 12:20:52   P10           2       
2011-06-22 20:20:52   P10           3       
2011-06-23 02:20:52   P10           4       
2011-06-23 08:20:52   P10           4
```

My ideal output is where any timestamp row beyond 23:59:59 is dropped except for the first instance

```
timestamp             patient_id    frequency
2011-06-22 12:20:52   P10           2       
2011-06-22 20:20:52   P10           3       
2011-06-22 23:59:59   P10           4
```

This is my existing code.

```
library(lubridate)

timestamps <- c('2011-06-22 12:20:52', '2011-06-22 12:20:52', '2011-06-22 12:20:52', '2011-06-22 12:20:52')
patient_ids <- c('P10', 'P10', 'P10', 'P10')
frequency <- c(2, 3, 4, 4)

# Extract the date from the first timestamp
date <- as.Date(timestamps[1])

# Calculate the time intervals based on the given frequencies
time_intervals <- as.difftime(24 / frequency, units = "hours")

# Generate new timestamps with the calculated time intervals for the remaining timestamps
new_timestamps <- c()
prev_timestamp <- as.POSIXct(timestamps[1])

for (interval in time_intervals) {
  next_timestamp <- prev_timestamp + interval
  if (hour(next_timestamp) >= 24) {
    next_timestamp <- as.POSIXct(paste(date + 1, "00:00:00"), tz = "UTC")
    break
  }
  new_timestamps <- c(new_timestamps, next_timestamp)
  prev_timestamp <- next_timestamp
}

# Create a data frame with the combined data
combined_data <- data.frame(timestamp = new_timestamps,
                            patient_id = rep(patient_ids[1], length(timestamps)),
                            frequency = frequency)

#dt_data <- as.POSIXct(combined_data$timestamp, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
combined_data$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(combined_data$timestamp, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")

print(combined_data)
```

Another coding attempt

```
library(lubridate)

timestamps <- c('2011-06-22 12:20:52', '2011-06-22 12:20:52', '2011-06-22 12:20:52', '2011-06-22 12:20:52')
patient_ids <- c('P10', 'P10', 'P10', 'P10')
frequency <- c(2, 3, 4, 4)

# Convert the timestamps to POSIXct
timestamps <- as.POSIXct(timestamps)

# Extract the date from the first timestamp
date <- as.Date(timestamps[1])

# Calculate the time intervals based on the given frequencies
time_intervals <- as.difftime(24 / frequency, units = "hours")

# Generate new timestamps with the calculated time intervals for the remaining timestamps
new_timestamps <- c()
prev_timestamp <- timestamps[1]

for (interval in time_intervals) {
  next_timestamp <- prev_timestamp + interval
  if (hour(next_timestamp) >= 24) {
    next_timestamp <- as.POSIXct(paste(date + 1, "00:00:00"), tz = "UTC")
    break
  }
  new_timestamps <- c(new_timestamps, next_timestamp)
  prev_timestamp <- next_timestamp
}

# Create a data frame with the combined data
combined_data <- data.frame(timestamp = c(timestamps[1], new_timestamps),
                            patient_id = rep(patient_ids[1], length(timestamps) + 1),
                            frequency = c(frequency[1], frequency))

print(combined_data)
```

This attempt gave the following output.

```
timestamp              patient_id   frequency
2011-06-22 12:20:52    P10          2       
2011-06-22 12:21:04    P10          2       
2011-06-22 12:21:12    P10          3       
2011-06-22 12:21:18    P10          4       
2011-06-22 12:21:24    P10          4
```

Comment: How do you arrive from, e. g., 2011-06-22 **11:21:04** (the first timestamp in your example input) at 2011-06-22 **12:20:52** (the first timestamp of your desired output? Shouldn't adding 12 hours (24 / frequency) yield 2011-06-23 23:21:04?

Comment: Hi.  I want to keep the first instance as 2011-06-22 12:20:52 and use the value derived from 24hours/frequency value to amend the time component to the desired time.  The 2011-06-22 11:21:04 is an artefact in the existing code, but should be 2011-06-22 12:20:52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it down into three steps:

1. calculate the nominal offsets
2. Add the offsets and keep the less of the offset time and 23:59:59 of the original day
3. remove duplicate timestamps

```
library(dplyr)

theData <- data.frame(
  timestamps = ymd_hms(timestamps), patient_ids, frequency
)

theData |> 
  mutate(
    # keep first row unchanged
    offset =  if_else(row_number() > 1, 24/frequency, 0) |> 
      # will need cumulative offset value
      cumsum() |> 
      # type conversion to use date-time addition
      hours(),
    # find max allow about time by rolling back a second from the next day
    maxTS = ceiling_date(timestamps, unit = "day") - seconds(1)
  ) |> 
  # calculate rowwise otherwise min will use entire column
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(
    timestamps = min(timestamps + offset, maxTS)
  ) |> 
  # remove helper columns
  select(timestamps, patient_ids, frequency) |> 
  # remove duplicates caused by calcs maxing out at the end of the day
  distinct(timestamps, patient_ids, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Many thanks Marcus... your code gives the desired output.  Very helpful.  Thank you.